# Excel data cleaning for Survey Monkey check all that apply

Tags: excel, restructuredtext, surveymonkey

Beginner user here - I have a few check all that apply + write in questions in Survey Monkey and I am trying to find a way to easily restructure and clean the data.

The question is a combo of check boxes + typing in the name (this is the "multiple text boxes" question type in Survey Monkey):

How did you hear about this program?

- City agency (type in name of agency)
- Community organization (type in name of agency)

I would like to restructure the original 5 columns of data (L-P) into 3 columns (L-N) that have the category type and the free-response text.

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM2ik.png)
[Desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogArf.png)

Comment: Use Power Query and unpivot. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27671495/9245853